# Swift: score increases twice because collision is detected twice?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm building a sprite kit game in swift and I need the score to increase by 1 when collision between 2 nodes is detected. The score is stored in a variable named `animalsCount` and is outputted to a label node:

```
    //Score count in stats bar
    //Animal score count

    animalsCount = 0

    animalsCountLabel.text = "\(animalsCount)"
    animalsCountLabel.fontSize = 45
    animalsCountLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    animalsCountLabel.position = CGPoint (x: 630, y: 40)

    addChild(animalsCountLabel)
```

The two sprite nodes that are colliding are `savior` and `chicken1`. Right now, I am keeping score and detecting collision using the following code:

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        //Chicken1

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue )  {

            println("chicken1 contact made")
            chicken1.hidden = true
            chicken1.setScale(0)

            animalsCount++
            animalsCountLabel.text = "\(animalsCount)"


        } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue)  {

            println("chicken1 contact made")
            chicken1.hidden = true
            chicken1.setScale(0)

        }
```

Score is not increased in the else if statement because it can't happen in my game.

The problem is that `animalsCount` increases by 2, not 1, every time `savior` and `chicken1` collide.

After some troubleshooting, I found out this is NOT because the score is being increased for both of the colliding bodies. This is not the case because only 1 line of code is ever satisfied. This is the only line that is satisfied:

```
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue)
```

The score goes up by 2 instead of 1 because `savior` seems to "bounce" off of `chicken1` so that `contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask` is set equal to `ColliderType.Savior.rawValue` TWICE every time collision appears to occur ONCE.

I don't know how to fix this problem. How do I make it so that collision is only detected ONCE and so the score is only increased once?

Comment: Just curious, why can't you just divide the score by 2 consistently? Will that cause a bug later on?

Comment: @iamdavidlam : You can't be sure there will consistently be two collision. It's better to fix the problem than working around it. @skyguy : Can you show us the declaration of your categories bitmasks and how you did assign them to your nodes ? If they are set correctly, you might want to use on your main node (the "savior" I guess) : `theSaviorNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES`.

Comment: @iamdavidlam lchamp is right; only sometimes would collision be detected twice. Other times the sprite nodes just grazed each other. If you were curious about the answer I figured it out below-

Answer (score 3):

I eventually solved the problem using an Int variable that controlled if statements so collision could only be detected once until the sprite node cycled through and the variable was reset.

I declared a variable called `chickenHasBeenGrabbed` and set it at 0 initially. Once collision had been detected that first time, I set `chickenHasBeenGrabbed` to 1. Only after `chickenHasBeenGrabbed` was set back to 0 could collision be detected again:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        //Chicken1

        if chickenHasBeenGrabbed == 0  {

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue )  {

            println("chicken1 contact made")
            chicken1.hidden = true
            chicken1.setScale(0)

            animalsCount += 1
            animalsCountLabel.text = "\(animalsCount)"

            chickenHasBeenGrabbed = 1


        } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue)  {

            println("chicken1 contact made")
            chicken1.hidden = true
            chicken1.setScale(0)

        }
        }

        else if chickenHasBeenGrabbed == 1 {

            if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue )  {

                println("nothing to do; chicken was already grabbed!")


            } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.rawValue)  {

                println("nothing to do; chicken was already grabbed!")

            }}
```